# How to include all asset sizes on build with Fastlane Gym

Tags: xcodebuild, fastlane

I am trying to include all sizes of an assets folder into a `.ipa` file used for testing. I am using Fastlane's Gym to build it.

The code below builds the artifact:

```rb
  gym(
    scheme: "MyApp",
    configuration: "Debug",
    silent: true,
    skip_archive: true,
    skip_codesigning: true,
    include_bitcode: false,
    derived_data_path: "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode",
    xcargs: "ENABLE_ONLY_ACTIVE_RESOURCES=NO")
```

I tried manually by doing this, no sucess:

```rb
sh("xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ../MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Debug ENABLE_ONLY_ACTIVE_RESOURCES=NO")
```

The code works but it's not including all the assets, I tried to add the `ENABLE_ONLY_ACTIVE_RESOURCES=NO` but it's not working. When taking screenshots the app assets (icons) are not visible on older devices. I need all assets size in the fat binary. Any idea how to do this?

I am using fastlane `2.143.0` and Xcode `11.3.1`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, I never had this kind of problem with `gym`.

If you don't need archiving, codesigning, etc... then a simple xcodebuild command might worth a try:

```
xcodebuild(
  workspace: 'MyApp',
  scheme: 'MyApp',
  configuration: 'Debug',
  destination: 'generic/platform=iOS'
)
```

`workspace` is the name of the .xcworkspace you want to build. If you’re not using a workspace, you need to change the variable to `project` in the above script.

Can you mention the device name + iOS version that you have problems with when creating screenshots? Also please give an example of a device + iOS version where the app image assets are visible as expected.